# Using useState hooks to update based on the previous state successively

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to enable button if both the checkboxes are checked, I have nonworking [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wpfepl)

I have added the only crux of functionality. Please look into the link for the nonworking demo

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';

    function App (){
      const [checked, toggleCheckbox] = useState({ checkbox1: false, checkbox2: false, disabled: true });
      const getDisabled = (state) => {
         if (state.checkbox1 || state.checkbox2) {
           return false;
         } else if (!state.checkbox1 && !state.checkbox2) {
           return true;
         } else {
           return true;
         }
       };
       const handleCheckbox = (checkbox) => {
        toggleCheckbox({
            ...checked,
            [checkbox]: !checked[checkbox],
            disabled: getDisabled(checked)
        });
        console.log(checked);
    };
    const checkDisable = checked.disabled ? 'disabled' : ''
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
           <label>
               <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="filled-in"
                    onChange={() => handleCheckbox('checkbox1')}
                    checked={checked.checkbox1}
                />
                <span className="black-text">Checkbox1</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="filled-in"
                    onChange={() => handleCheckbox('checkbox2')}
                    checked={checked.checkbox2}
                />
                <span className="black-text">checkbox2</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a className={checkDisable} href="#!">
                Next Step
            </a>
        </div>
   </div>
  );
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The functionality should be as follows:

1. The button should be enabled only if both the checkboxes are checked
2. On unchecking anyone checkboxes it should disable the button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply check the state of both checkbox values.

```
  const isDisabled = !(checked.checkbox1 && checked.checkbox2)
  const checkDisable = isDisabled ? 'disabled' : ''
```

No need to change elsewhere.

*Forked stackblitz link.*
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jscqwr?file=index.js

[image: demo]

---

### Answer to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793909/using-usestate-hooks-to-update-based-on-the-previous-state-successively/57794138#comment102021603_57794138).

> Hey, that worked! I could see in the log that the state one step below the updated state for an instance after clicking in the first checkbox { checkbox1: false, checkbox: false, disabled: false } after clicking the second checkbox the log { checkbox1: true, checkbox: false, disabled: false }

The reason you are seeing outdated state is because the state updator `toggleCheckbox` batches the update, thus you'd need to check for the updated status in an effect, which monitors the updated status.

[image: how to console]

---

### Dynamic number of checkboxes.

I've updated the stack to track dynamic number of checkboxes.

New fork~
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pl1e2n

Looks like this.
[image]

```
function App() {
  const length = 6;
  1️⃣ Generate the initial checkbox states - this prevents un/controlled component error.
  const initialCheckboxes = Array
    .from({ length }, (_, i) => i + 1)
    .reduce((acc, id) => (acc[id] = false, acc), {})

  const [checked, toggleCheckbox] = useState(initialCheckboxes);
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false)

  const handleCheckbox = id => {
    toggleCheckbox(previous => ({
      ...previous,
      [id]: !previous[id]
    }));
  };

  2️⃣ Update the disable state when the checkbox is selected.
  useEffect(() => {
      Enable when all checkboxes are not checked - 
    setIsDisabled(!Object.values(checked).every(_ => !!_))
  }, [checked])

  3️⃣ Dynamically generate checkboxes
  const checkboxElements = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i + 1)
    .map(id => (
      <div key={id}>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            className="filled-in"
            onChange={() => handleCheckbox(id)}
            checked={checked[id]}
          />
          <span className="black-text">Checkbox{id}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    ))


  return (
    <div>
      {checkboxElements}
      <div>
        <a className={isDisabled ? 'disabled' : ''} href="#!">
          Next Step
                            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, that worked! I could see in the log that the state one step below the updated state

for an instance after clicking in the first checkbox 
{ checkbox1: false, checkbox: false, disabled: false }
after clicking the second checkbox the log
{ checkbox1: true, checkbox: false, disabled: false }

Comment: You are logging stale state thus you get outdated value being logged.

Comment: I'm using two useStates now https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wpfepl updated this link! Can you check?

Comment: @lost_in_magento You don't actually need another state, `disabled`, to track the disabled status. You could simply use the "computed" value `const isDisabled = !(checked.checkbox1 && checked.checkbox2)` to enable/disable the "Next Step".

Comment: If I have 6 checkboxes to be checked and then enable the button the code will look bit clumsy so remove the logic from there I thought of using two useState()

Comment: @lost_in_magento I've forked another one to create a dynamic version of input checkboxes. Checkout the updated reply and in-line comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation with comments it really helped! Can you provide updated fork link! Seems to have old code

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation with comments it really helped! Can you provide an updated fork link! Seems to have old code

Comment: @lost_in_magento Woops, sorry about that. I've added the fork and also here it is in case - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pl1e2n